# i have a problem when i try to install new plugin cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 '@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 (or use the name yourself!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Comment: i have the same problem with @ionic-enterprise/identity-vault @Raghuram Sadineni

Comment: refer this:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/enterprise/setup

Comment: I cannot access the section dedicated to "Native plugin keys" in the ionic hub platform, I think I have to pay to have a entreprise account?

Comment: no, even if I created an account and I can create applications in the ionic hub platform but there is a part explained in the documentation which is "native plugin keys" I can't find it, I don't have access to multiple parts

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

You see the difference? @Raghuram